# Adding onClick for icon link?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

How can I add onClick for icon when it has `link` true ?

```
<Input size='huge' icon={{ name: 'plus', circular: true, link: true }}  placeholder='Add...' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this :

```
icon={{ name: 'eye', circular: true, link: true, onClick:(props.iconClicked)  }}
```